# Has anyone used ubuntu desktop 12.04, and installed the updated ruby on rails on it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I keep getting ruby 1.8.7, and rails 2.3.14 when I want the latest, but it doesn't allow me to update. I am still new to linux an the ubuntu OS so that's not helping? All the directions online are old like 2007, 2009, 2010 so they don't apply well to current ruby on rails 2012 times. I hope someone can point me in the right directions.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Hartl's RailsTutorial also has a great chapter on getting (nearly) everything needed for Rails development going.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-rubygems